# Where will the Intermediate result be stored during segmentation?

Tags: x86-16

In 8086, 20-bit address is generated with two 16-bit registers by using segmentation. The first 16bit address is multiplied by 10 and the result will be added to second 16bit address.
when multiplied by 10 it will generate a 5digit HEXA number which is 20bit long.
where will this intermediate result of 20bit (obtained when multiplied by 10) be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere. The address appears on the corresponding pins ([AD0-AD19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8086#Buses_and_operation)) of the chip when it needs to access memory. The calculation is performed internally with dedicated logic. For example there is no actual multiplication by 0x10: the segment bits are directly paired to higher-numbered bits of the offset in corresponding [adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29) (item 3 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aIntel_8086_block_scheme.svg)).

Comment: I'm interested to know about that internal dedicated logic. However I got the answer, the shifted address will be stored in two separate registers. We can store the final 20bit address in these two registers also, but , in order to make the address locating easier, we go for segmentation. (You would have known about the 100 houses example, which is arranged in 10X10 format)